# the program exits after i giving String input

Tags: java, input

```
package javaapplication1;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class arrrrr {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String n,m;

      BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

       ArrayList l1=new ArrayList();
        l1.add("india");
        l1.add("chennai");
        l1.add("tamilnadu");
        l1.add("mumbai");
         n=br.readLine();
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            if(n==l1.get(j))
            {
                System.out.println("The array location  :"+"l1["+j+"]");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to find a array location. When given input, the program exits automatically. If I assign the value to n, it works perfect. I want to know why the programs exits after giving input.

Comment: Do not forget to add a `br.readLine()` at the end to make your program wait for some input prior to exiting.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
if(n==l1.get(j))
```

to this:

```
if(n.equals(l1.get(j)))
```

Reason is `==` checks references, but equals will check if strings are equal.